# PHP or SQL for Large Data and Sub/Related Data Sets

Tags: php, sql-server, performance, subquery

I can't imagine I'm the first or the last to ask about this, but I was unable to find the answer by searching.

I have a large dataset of orders in SQL Server. I need to return every order with each of their line items and each of their payments. I'm looking for the most efficient way to query and iterate through this data. I am using PHP/MSSQL to pull the orders, looping through those with foreach and querying for a list of items and payments would be incredibly inefficient.

I've thought about creating a union to create one massive dataset that has a bunch of columns, one of which is a column indicating what type of record (payment,line_item,order_data). But that also seems pretty inefficient.

**This is an outline of the process I have been working with:**

```
<?php
    // query for orders
    $records = sql_function("select * from v_migration_orders");

    $json_output = array();
    foreach($record as $r){
        $data['order']['org_code'] = $r['org_code'];
        $data['order']['po_number'] = $r['po_number'];
        ...

        // query for line items
        $data['order']['line_items'] = array();
        $items = sql_function("select * from v_migration_line_items where invoice = ".sanitize_function($r['invoice']));

        foreach($items as $i){
            $line['line_item_type'] = $i['line_item_type'];
            $line['sku'] = $i['sku'];
            $line['legacy_id'] = $i['legacy_id'];
            ...
            array_push($data['order']['line_items'],$line);
        }

        // query for payments
        $data['order']['payments'] = array();
        $payments = sql_function("select * from v_migration_payments where invoice = ".sanitize_function($r['invoice']));

        foreach($payments as $p){
            $pyt['Amount'] = $p['Amount'];
            $pyt['payment_type'] = $p['payment_type'];
            $pyt['Check_Number'] = $p['Check_Number'];
            ...
            array_push($data['order']['payments'],$pyt);
        }


        array_push($json_output,$data);
    }

    echo json_encode($json_output);
```

With a focus on efficiency, I'm hoping someone in the community can help point me in the right direction here. The number of calls from the web server to the database server are triple what I'd like them to be. The alternative I can think of is to find a way to place them all into a single trip to the database and have PHP parse the full response once it receives it.

Below is the structure of the needed data I've put into views. Note that I'm using the integer, `Invoice` as the key to join on.

**v_migration_orders:**

- `line_type` (value is: "Order")
- `Org_Code`
- `PO_Number`
- `Invoice`
- `Tax_Total`
- `Order_Total`
- `EMAIL`
- `status`
- `order_t_stamp`
- `order_legacy_id`

**v_migration_orders_line_items:**

- `line_type` (value is "line_item")
- `line_item_type`
- `Invoice`
- `sku`
- `legacy_id`
- `TITLE`
- `quantity`
- `unit_price`

**v_migration_orders_payments:**

- `line_type` (value is "payment")
- `Invoice`
- `Amount`
- `payment_type`
- `Check_Number`
- `Card_Processor`
- `cc_message`
- `card_type`
- `cardholder_name`
- `card_expiry`
- `payment_token`
- `payment_t_stamp`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of output are you trying to produce? And do you have something that works inefficiently at this point, or are you still in the planning stage?

Comment: Please show us the structure of the tables involved as well as what you have tried.

Comment: How are you using the data?   Also are you familiar with datamarts?  you can denormalize the data each night in DM tables, so you minimize the number of rows and tables to hold the data for each order.  This will increase the efficiency of your access, but to fully answer question please explain how you will be using the data returned.

Comment: I'm setting up a JSON data migration from our legacy order system so that our new system can ingest that order data. I'm completely rewriting the queries as per a changing spec from the vendor and with > 100,000 orders, I'm hoping to find a way to execute this efficiently.

Comment: have you considered an ETL tool?  check out Talend Open Studio https://www.talend.com/download/  (select the data Integration free download).  This will allow you to grab your data straight from the tables, manipulate, join, etc. and produce JSON files.  That is how I would approach this.  It will take a little bit of time to learn the tool but worth the effort.

Comment: @Dave I've updated the question with an example of usage, structure of the data, and my thoughts.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm setting up a JSON Feed.

Comment: @ELaRoche I'm not looking for a long term solution for this project as we are just exporting the data for now. I'll definitely look into it for future projects though. Thank you!